# How to apply deseasonalised residuals to data?

Tags: r, residuals, seasonality

My data looks like this:
[image: Original data]

There is a weekly pattern of seasonality and a yearly pattern. And the variance is not constant over time (so no arima, but I want to model an arima-Garch suggested by the literature). I smoothed the data with a ma-smoother:

```
detrend = ma(data$b, order = 7) # order 7 for weekly seasonality
```

Then I wanted to estimate the seasonality with the following model:

```
 cos.t <- cos(2*pi*time(detrend)/365) #assumes cos. pattern 
seasonal = lm(detrend ~ time(detrend) + cos.t) #fit model
d1 = resid(seasonal) # deseasonalised data
```

d1 gives me the process which is left after seasonality and trend is removed. This is only the residual term. So when I want to continue with my data do I continue with the residual term?

```
model1 = auto.arima(d1)
```

If not, how can I put my regression results into the original data, and deseasonalize it, so that it fluctuates around the mean of data$b again?
The stl() and decompose() function does not work in my case (And I would like to apply my regression). I am actually more looking for a code like the seasadj() for stl data, applied to my results, unless it is normal to continue with the residuals.

I tried my best to give a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(7)
x <- diffinv(rnorm(831))
x <- x[-c(1:101)]
plot(x)

detrend = ma(x, order = 7) # order 7 for weekly seasonality

## filter seasonality
cos.t <- cos(2*pi*time(detrend)/365)#assumes cos. pattern 
seasonal = lm(detrend ~ time(detrend)+ cos.t)#fit model

plot(x)
lines(fitted(seasonal), col="red")

d1 = resid(seasonal)

auto.arima(d1) # Can I model the residuals as an arima to learn the structure 
#of the original series?
model1 = arima(d1, order = c(3,0,2))

arch.test(model1) # in this case the variance is constant over time
```

I want to model a garchfit(d1,...) later on.

Comment: "how can I put my regression results into the original data, and deseasonalize it, so that it fluctuates around the mean of data$b again?" Is this a question about statistics, or about how to use R?

Comment: I must admit that I do not have some basic statistical knowledge in that case. But theoretical books do not help me at this point. So it is indeed a question about applied statistics and how to translate it to R. Is it ok to ask questions like this on this forum?

Comment: Sure I think so. I'm new here too.